# What is the village in Shichinin no Samurai (7 Samurai) called?

Tags: seven-samurai

I watched and rewatched the movie Shichinin no Samurai by Mifune about 3 times, but I still can't find out what the name of the mountain village might be, though that might be lost in translation, especially since I don't know more than a few terms of Japanese. Was it even named (in the original dub)?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mention the name of the village anywhere throughout the movie.

Comment: not even in the japanese?

Comment: @Trish I have seen it in Japanese with English subtitles so I don't know if they say it in Japanese but the subtitle didn't include it, but I don't think the subtitle missed it. Also there is no mention of the name of the village anywhere in the internet.

Comment: That's why I ask if it might have been lost in translation. because there are only subtitles and my Japanese is barely existent.